# Simple way to read the memory of another process in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm running ruby on my Windows 7 machine. How can I do the following with Ruby(1.9.3):

1. Get all the processes details (like PID, Image Name, Memory Usage) running on the machine &
2. Get the memory contents in plain text format for each of the above processes so that I will be able to parse it..

For first task should I use windows `tasklist` command and parse it for the required information or some better alternative exists.

And for second I have read a lot and still confused, whether I should create a `ruby extension` or use `FFI` or use some kind of `WinAPI` function `ReadProcessMemory`..

This stack overflow question resembles my situation [How can I read the memory of another process in Python in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794579/how-can-i-read-the-memory-of-another-process-in-python-in-windows)

Comment: Do you want to know how much RAM every process running on your computer is using? Have a look at the `top` unix command.

Comment: @plly I interpreted that OP wants something like core dump or the sort in some format.

Comment: @sawa You are right, I want the dump process wise..

Answer (score 0):

If you 're on Linux please read this previous post

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux

about

```
/proc/<id>/maps
/proc/<id>/pagemap
/proc/<id>/mem
```

This could be easily ported in Ruby

list processes is like list /proc folder
For processes who is not a child of your process, you have to look to :

http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/p/Ptrace-0.9.3/Ptrace/MemArea.html

Comment: ouch :) i haven't see this detail