# Dynamic way to work with memory in python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, memory, memory-management

I recently used a program called Cheat Engine, and what it does is you specify which process you want to work with from a list of currently running processes (usually used for pc gaming), and after you've got one picked out, you can run a search for existing values and keep track of changes made to those values via sequential scans in your memory to help trim your list of results down to a single memory address for the relevant thing you're trying to work with.

Once you've found the memory address and its value you were looking for, you can edit it and return that back to the program which I found to be very interesting. I want to learn how to do low level work like this, and [I read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794579/how-can-i-read-the-memory-of-another-process-in-python-in-windows) here which had an answer I thought would put me off to an excellent start:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

OpenProcess = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
ReadProcessMemory = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
CloseHandle = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

pid = 4044   # I assume you have this from somewhere.
address = 0x1000000  # Likewise; for illustration I'll get the .exe header.

buffer = c_char_p("The data goes here")
bufferSize = len(buffer.value)
bytesRead = c_ulong(0)

processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
if ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, bufferSize, byref(bytesRead)):
    print "Success:", buffer
else:
    print "Failed."

CloseHandle(processHandle)
```

It's basic enough for me to get a good grasp of what they're doing, but in their code, they use a hardcoded memory address. A specific memory address is closer to my end point, not my starting point.

What I'd like to do is be able to pass a process ID to my script, have it read all the memory associated with it (cheat engine's memory scan will range from 0000000000000000-7fffffffffffffff), and I'd like to make changes in whichever program is associated with the process, then run queries for the value matching up with the changes made until I've singled it down to an address. Then I'd like to be able to write over that value and pass that back to the program.

From what I've been reading around, it looks like ctypes and kernel32 are the way to go if I'd like to do this in python, but I'm stuck on how to dynamically retrieve memory addresses associated with a PID and can't branch out from this basic script until I've figured it out. How would one go about finding these?

I've attached a screenshot of what this looks like in Cheat Engine in case my explanation wasn't clear enough.[image]

--edit--
I've also read through the ctypes doc and though they had different examples where kernel32 was being used, they didn't have anything that explained how to work with it. One hint I saw on the page was

"To find out the correct calling convention you have to look into the C header file or the documentation for the function you want to call."

I'm having trouble finding this information. What would one typically type in when looking for these?