# Reading process memory by pywin32 giving incorrect result

Tags: python, pywin32

I am trying to read memory from a game process (Just like what Cheat Engine does). I have study different posts, like:

- [Get HWND of each Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653168/get-hwnd-of-each-window)
- [How can I read the memory of another process in Python in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794579/how-can-i-read-the-memory-of-another-process-in-python-in-windows)
- [WriteProcessMemory and
  ReadProcessMemory](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2gg5wb/writeprocessmemory_and_readprocessmemory/)

And then, I am able to piece out my first memory reading script. Basically, it has 2 steps. Getting process handle, and then read the memory address from the handle.

But I value I get is wrong.

### My code

```
import win32gui,win32com.client
import win32api
import ctypes
import win32ui
import win32process 
from ctypes import wintypes

### Initializing functions and permissions ###
OpenProcess = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess
ReadProcessMemory = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory # Method 1

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020
### End of Initializing session

### Getting process handle ###
HWND = win32ui.FindWindow(None,'My Game').GetSafeHwnd()
PID = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND)[1]
processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PID) # Why is it zero
### End of Getting process handle ###

### Reading value of a Memory Address ###

ADDRESS = 0x0111FF62
buffer = ctypes.c_char_p("Hello, World".encode('utf-8'))
bufferSize = len(buffer.value)
bytesRead = ctypes.c_ulong(0)

memory_value = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, ADDRESS, buffer, bufferSize, ctypes.byref(bytesRead)) # Why is it zero
print('Memory Value = ', memory_value)
```

> Memory Value =  0

### The true value I get from Memory scanning software

[image]

I have double check if my HWND value is correct by using the function `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(HWND )`. It does bring the windows to Foreground. So I am pretty sure my program wrong until the line for HWND.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenProcess` is failing, likely because `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is not granted. You only need read access, so change `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` to `PROCESS_VM_READ`, check the return value to make sure it is not zero.

Documentation for [`OpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess)

> If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the
>   specified process.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`. To get extended error
>   information, call `GetLastError`.

Note that Windows stores text in UTF16 format, not UTF8