# Is there any way that I can read the entire data in RAM that is active?

Tags: python, ram

I am writing a program but I am curious to know when I am running it I want to see what are the operations going on in the RAM. I want to see how RAM access the data and run it. And I want to see the data stores on RAM. How can I see the data written on RAM?

Comment: Or this: [How can I read the memory of another process in Python in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794579/how-can-i-read-the-memory-of-another-process-in-python-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind that **python interpreter** actually executes the code you're writing in python. This interpreter is usually just an application running on some operating system (linux, windows etc. unless we're talking about some hard-embedded stuff, but I assume not). So, we've got abstraction over hardware (the aforementioned RAM) in form of the operating system and another abstraction in form of python language (which is a high-level programming language, and unlike in assembly, you don't have full control over what happens in the memory or registers for each line). There's a concept of [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) in context of operating systems - I recommend reading a bit about it. What you'll eventually learn is that from within the OS, the mapping between RAM and your process memory might not necessarily be one-to-one all the time.

If you simply want to look up your process' stack and variables, I recommend [PDB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).