# How to change the value stored in memory address? PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management

Lets say that memory address 0688DFA4 stores a value 120. How to change it to 124 using
python? Is there a module supplied for this kind of task?

> > > import ctypes
> > > memfield = (ctypes.c_char).from_address(0x0688DFA4)
> > > I tried but it didn't change.

I use gnu/linux. Debian

Comment: Perhaps combine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794579/how-can-i-read-the-memory-of-another-process-in-python-in-windows with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I use gnu/linux Debian @PeterWood

Comment: I tried but it didn't change. @DejeneT.