# Can I Access Specific Memory Addresses Manually Via Python

Tags: python, memory, ram, memory-address

I am working on a project where I am interfacing(?) with another program. This other program has no way for me to interface with it, so, I need to pull values out of memory. I have already found the addresses where these values are stored relative to the MZ Start address listed in the programs PE header. I simply need to look at that address and get its value. Is there a way to do this in Python, or will I need a different language?

I used Cheat Engine to find the memory address relative to the MZ Start address listed in the programs PE header. However, I have no way to interface with Cheat Engine in order to do something with the value it is looking at. Then I had the idea to manually look at that address while the program is running with a python script. However, I am unsure of where to begin.

Here's what I know:

First line of memory starts at address: 0x00CC0000

It always starts here.

Hexadecimal Address: 00CC0000(StartOfMem)+841984(Offset) = 0x01501984

This is where the pointer is stored in memory. I have verified that it is always in this location.

This pointer points to the memory address of a UI class object in the program I am trying to interface with, this object contains data I want to read.

If I dereference the pointer it will give me another memory address. Let's call this value AddressAtPointer.

I know the two things I am looking have an offset of 43C and 434 from AddressAtPointer and are 4 byte integers.

Is there a way for me to read the data at these specific memory addresses?

Comment: pwntools can definitely do this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. But, I will warn you that reading and writing to specific memory addresses is the wrong tool to solve this problem. The right tool is probably [ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python) or [SWIG](https://www.swig.org/). In particular, that would save you from needing to figure out what the right offsets are.

I figure you're going to ignore that advice, so here's how to write arbitrary memory addresses.

```
import ctypes
foo = ctypes.c_char.from_address(0x00000000)
foo.value = 1
```

This will write a byte of 0x01 to the address zero. You can change the address by changing `0x00000000`. You can change the value written by changing the 1. You can change the size of the write by changing c_char to [something else](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types).

Reading a memory address is the same, except instead of `foo.value = 1`, you have `variable = foo.value`.

All of the above assumes you're in the same address space as your target.

Comment: I need to read from that memory address. I know that the data at that is stored as a 4 byte integer value. (Technically its a bool, it is only ever 1 or 0). Would I just be able to do print(foo) and see what is at that address? Also, the address that I want to look at is being used by a separate program.

Comment: You can do that but it's OS specific. For Windows see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794579/how-can-i-read-the-memory-of-another-process-in-python-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

No -- Not through python directly. Python is a memory-safe language and therefore doesn't allow for interaction directly with memory.
Your best bet might be using CPython to call a C function which does the memory-trickery that you want.

This is also an extremely fragile way of getting data: Memory addresses may not be the same between different machines, different operating systems, or even different executions of the same program (ASLR is a feature that randomizes memory addresses every time a program starts up, and this may be enabled)

Comment: pwntools provides wrappers around c function in python for this sort of thing

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have provided more information in the post that might be helpful.